# Transition to Fragment by clicking GridView element using animation

Tags: animation, gridview

I want to expand the layout from circle "LAB". I have a `GridView` and by clicking on the grid element, i.e "LAB", the outer layout should expand from that circle by using animation

Link for Image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7P6eljszm3xU1A1cjhUb29XbGs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You should update the permissions on the link to your image so people can view it.

Comment: @CoryCharlton - I have changed the link...Like that circle in image,I have a same circular element in my gridview ,so by clicking on that grid element that outer layout should expand from that element